# trouble : WAS - Worklight with JMS adapter

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have developped a Worklight (v6) Application. The Worklight server runs on a Websphere Application Server 8.5.5 (JMS provider).

When I invoke my adapter, I get this exception in the WAS log :

[12/13/13 13:20:02:860 CET] 00000093 JMSConnection E com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSConnectionManager onException FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received: com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. Closing the connection. [project testJMS]

I have followed 2 ways to make my JMS queue, connection factory, etc.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.iis.infoservdir.user.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_isd_user_creating_jms_que_cx_fact.html (from topic 1 to 5)

and this one :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Worklight%20and%20Application%20Center%20advanced%20tutorials/page/Worklight%20JMS%20adapter%20-%20Using%20the%20Liberty%20Profile%20integration%20with%20the%20WAS%20full%20profile%20SIBus

two tutorials are similars (using WAS full profile). In my case, the queue is local (Woklight ans the queue are in the WAS). So, I let under commentary "namingConnection" tag  in my JMS adapter.

But I do not understand why I get this exception. It seems that is classcast Exception. But how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Can you post the full version of Worklight that you are using (including the build number)? This was a defect that was fixed in later versions. There are workarounds if upgrading is not possible but I can better help you if I know the version of Worklight you are using.

Comment: the version is 6.0.0.20130614-0631.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defect is still present in the 6.0.0.20130614-0631 version of worklight. You will need to upgrade to the 6.0.0.1 (20130909-1459) Fix Pack to get the fix.

If upgrading isn't an option, there is a bit of a hacky workaround that does work with no adverse side effects.

Edit:

Use 6.0.020130926 instead of the above version as mentioned by Idan.

Comment: It would be better to upgrade to 6.0.020130926, which is the official 6.0.0.1 fix pack 1.

Comment: Thanks Idan. I went and checked the exact build that had the fix was included in, but the official build is better.